# py.test gives Coverage.py warning: Module sample.py was never imported

Tags: pytest, coverage.py

I ran a sample code from this thread. 
[How to properly use coverage.py in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517137/how-to-properly-use-coverage-py-in-python)

However, when I executed this command `py.test test.py --cov=sample.py`
it gave me a warning, therefore, no report was created.

```
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.12, pytest-3.2.3, py-1.4.34, pluggy-0.4.0
rootdir: /media/sf_Virtual_Drive/ASU/CSE565_testand 
validation/Assignments/temp, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.5.1
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

test.py ...Coverage.py warning: Module sample.py was never imported. (module-not-imported)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
```

Anyone has an idea why `coverage.py` does not work?

hence, if I run `coverage run -m py.test test.py`separately, it does not show any warning.

Comment: I think `--cov` wants a module name, not a filename.  Try `--cov=sample` instead.

Answer (score 27):

Short answer: you need to run with the module name, not the file name: `pytest --cov sample test.py`

Long answer:

One comment in the answer you linked ([How to properly use coverage.py in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36517137/how-to-properly-use-coverage-py-in-python#comment81103062_36524004)) explains that this doesn't seem to work if the file you are trying to get the coverage of is a module imported by the test. I was able to reproduce that:

***./sample.py***

```
def add(*args):
    return sum(args)
```

***./test.py***

```
from sample import add

def test_add():
    assert add(1, 2) == 3
```

And I get the same error:

```
$ pytest --cov sample.py test.py
========================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-4.3.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0
rootdir: /path/to/directory, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.6.1
collected 1 item

test.py .                                                                                                                                                                                          [100%]Coverage.py warning: Module sample.py was never imported. (module-not-imported)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
/path/to/directory/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytest_cov/plugin.py:229: PytestWarning: Failed to generate report: No data to report.

  self.cov_controller.finish()
WARNING: Failed to generate report: No data to report.
```

However, when using the module name instead:

```
pytest --cov sample test.py
========================================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.2, pytest-4.3.1, py-1.8.0, pluggy-0.9.0
rootdir: /path/to/directory, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.6.1
collected 1 item

test.py .                                                                                                                                                                                          [100%]

---------- coverage: platform darwin, python 3.7.2-final-0 -----------
Name        Stmts   Miss  Cover
-------------------------------
sample.py       2      0   100%
```

The [pytest-cov](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html) documentation seems to indicate you can use a `PATH`, but it might not be working in all cases...

Answer (score 8):

tl;dr
Use `coverage` to generate the statistics file `.coverage` and then create a report that scopes to your specific file only.

```
coverage run -m pytest .\test\test_named_prng.py
coverage html --include=named_prng.py
```

### Situation

Let's suppose you have some python files in your package, and you also have test cases within a single test file (`test/test_named_prng.py`). You want to measure the code coverage of your test file on one specific file within your package (`named_prng.py`).

```
\namedPrng
│   examples.py
│   named_prng.py
│   README.md
│   timeit_meas.py
│   __init__.py
│
└───test
        test_named_prng.py
        __init__.py
```

Here `namedPrng/__init__.py` imports `examples.py` and `named_prng.py`, where the other init file is empty.
[An example with files is available on my GitHub.](https://github.com/danieltuzes/studies/commit/18f8c8c776a4b65c13a850c30cb6fffdf55adbe8)

### Problem

Your problem is that with `pytest` or with `coverage` you cannot scope the report to your specific file (`named_prng.py`), because every other file imported from your package is also included in the report.

#### root cause

If you have an `__init__.py` in the level where the module you want to import is located, then `__init__.py` may import more files than necessary as the `__init__.py` will be executed. There are options to tell pytest and coverage to restrict which modules you want to investigate, but if they involve further modules from your package, they will be analysed too.

#### symptom with pytest

The option `--cov` of the package `pytest-cov`, which is used if you issue `pytest` with the option `--cov`, doesn't work if the (sub)module you want to create the coverage test on was imported from `__init__.py`.

If you run pytest (from `namedPrng`) with

```
pytest .\test\test_named_prng.py --cov --cov-report=html
```

you will get a report every `.py` file except the `timeit_meas.py`, because it is never imported: nor the test, nor its init, nor the imported `named_prng.py`, nor its init.

If you run pytest with

```
pytest .\test\test_named_prng.py --cov=./ --cov-report=html
```

then you explicitly tell `coverage` (invoked with `pytest`) to include everything in your level, therefore every `.py` file will be included in the report.

You'd like to tell coverage to create the report only on the source code of `named_prng.py`, but if you specify your module to `--cov` with

```
pytest .\test\test_named_prng.py --cov=named_prng --cov-report=html
```

or with `--cov=named_prng.py` you will get a warning:

```
Coverage.py warning: Module named_prng.py was never imported. (module-not-imported)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
WARNING: Failed to generate report: No data to report.
```

#### symptom with `coverage`

One can run the coverage and report separately and hope that more detailed options can be passed to coverage.

By issuing

```
coverage run -m pytest .\test\test_named_prng.py
coverage html
```

you get the same report on the 5 `.py` files. If you try to tell `coverage` to use only `named_prng.py` by

```
coverage run --source=named_prng -m pytest .\test\test_named_prng.py
```

or with `--source=named_prng.py`, you will get a warning

```
Coverage.py warning: Module named_prng.py was never imported. (module-not-imported)
Coverage.py warning: No data was collected. (no-data-collected)
```

and no report will be created.

### Solution

You need to use the `--include` switch for `coverage` which unfortunately cannot be passed to `pytest` in a CLI.

#### Use `coverage` CLI

You can restrict the scope of investigation during code coverage calculation time:

```
coverage run --include=named_prng.py -m pytest .\test\test_named_prng.py
coverage html
```

or at reporting time.

```
coverage run -m pytest .\test\test_named_prng.py
coverage html --include=named_prng.py
```

#### Use `pytest` + settings file

One can call `pytest` with detailed configuration via a config file. Where you issue `pytest`, set up a `.coveragerc` file with the content

```
[run]
include = named_prng.py
```

Check [coverage's description](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#run) on the possible options and patterns.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by running coverage first on your test file then generate the report as follows:

`coverage run test.py`

`coverage report -m`

Answer (score 0):

I had a different problem than the answers mentioned here, so I will add another answer.

The error in the original question may also be raised if you configured your `pyproject.toml` file with the wrong directory. For instance, if your source code is in a folder called `my_code`, make sure you have:

```ini
[tool.coverage.run]
source = ['my_code']
```

on your `pyproject.toml` file. More info at: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html

Answer (score 0):

For me this was a really simple error, the *directory* had to be the same name as the file under test else it didn't collect coverage.

A really weird one for sure...